# Files installed from debian package with dpkg do not belong to root

Tags: linux, deb, dpkg

I created a binary package with this command:

```
dpkg-deb --build -z9 -Zlzma $(DEB_SRC_DIR) $(DEB_DEST_DIR)
```

and install it on my Ubuntu 12.04 with this command:

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/package
```

The contents of the package I think are irrelevant.

Despite the sudo command the files in the installation directory belong to the current user and not to root as I expected.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to run the `dpkg-deb` command with `fakeroot`:

```
`fakeroot dpkg-deb ...`
```

(This will only help if the files in the source directory already have the correct ownership, which they probably dont.  The problem you're actually trying to solve here, is to create an archive with files in it that belong to user `root`, which is where fakeroot theoretically helps.)

Let me say though, that what you are doing is not the best way for creating a binary package (far from it).

Instead, create a `debian/` directory with `dh_make` (from the `dh-make` package), and edit the control file and changelog accordingly.  You also need a file `debian/install` that lists what files you are installing and where they should go.  There are various guides on the net (and on Stack Overflow) that explain this process.  For example, look at the *Debian New Maintainers' Guide*.

You can then use `dpkg-buildpackage` to create a real, standard-conforming Debian package with your files in a reproducible way.

`dpkg-deb` is a low-level tool for manipulating existing `deb` files; it's not meant to be used for package creation.

Comment: Packages created with dpkg-deb can not be used in apt repositories.
They also doesn't containt the md5sum of files so it's hard for users to know if a file is the original from the package or has been modified.
They also are not signed, which means users can not be sure whether it was you that created this package or not.
So yeah, I also recomend dpkg-buildpackage.